# Error running `gatsby build` with Kentico Kontent

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, kentico-kontent

I have a project that used both [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) and [Kentico Kontent](https://www.kontent.ai). I've been working well in dev using both `gatsby develop` and `npm run develop` on my local machine (Windows 10). Typicall, the output looks like this:

```
$ npm run develop

success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.169s
success load plugins - 0.426s
success onPreInit - 0.004s
success initialize cache - 0.007s
success copy gatsby files - 0.067s
success onPreBootstrap - 1.357s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.545s
success source and transform nodes - 1.740s
success building schema - 0.358s
success createPages - 0.068s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.063s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.002s
success update schema - 0.030s   
success extract queries from components - 0.177s
success write out requires - 0.027s
success write out redirect data - 0.007s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.003s
⠀
info bootstrap finished - 7.596 s
⠀
success run queries - 0.125s - 61/61 489.34/s
⠀
You can now view <project name> in the browser.
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  http://localhost:8000/___graphql
⠀
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use gatsby build
⠀
success Building development bundle - 3.319s
```

When I run either `gatsby build` or `npm run build`, this always fails and I see the following error/output:

```
$ npm run build

> <project name>@1.1.1 build C:\projects\<client>\<project name>
> gatsby build

success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.155s
success load plugins - 0.435s
success onPreInit - 0.004s
success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.019s
success initialize cache - 0.008s
success copy gatsby files - 0.076s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.028s

 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"@kentico/gatsby-source-kontent" threw an error while running the createSchemaCustomization lifecycle:



not finished createSchemaCustomization - 0.549s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! <project name>@1.1.1 build: `gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the <project name>@1.1.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mattn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-24T12_10_17_984Z-debug.log
```

Looking at the suggested log file, I see:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~prebuild: <project name>@1.1.1
6 info lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: <project name>@1.1.1
7 verbose lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: PATH: <My Env Variables Path>
9 verbose lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: CWD: C:\projects\<client>\<project name>
10 silly lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gatsby build' ]
11 silly lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle <project name>@1.1.1~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: working-at-ridgeway@1.1.1 build: `gatsby build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid <project name>@1.1.1
15 verbose cwd C:\projects\<client>\<project name>
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error <project name>@1.1.1 build: `gatsby build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the <project name>@1.1.1 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Is there another way to get detail on the error so that I can find a resolution? I've tried updating and installing npm packages and running a 'clean' on that gatsby project, but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resulted in new logging capabilities for [version 6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kentico/gatsby-source-kontent?activeTab=versions) of [@kentico/gatsby-source-kontent](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/@kentico/gatsby-source-kontent/).

So just run `gatsby develop --verbose`, or `gatsby build --verbose` to get logs from package to the terminal.

[Official information](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-gatsby-packages/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-kontent#logging)
[Implementation details](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-gatsby-packages/pull/121)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, however, I believe the development configuration uses [different environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript) than production build (if using client-side javascript). Could you try to adjust env. variables according to gatsby's docu? What OS do you use? There are some [significant differences in accessing .env variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#server-side-nodejs) for Linux and Windows, as well.

If this does not work could you pls create an issue in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-source-kontent/issues) and provide steps (or project) to reproduce? Thank you!

Edit: I'd also give it a try to use [Gatsby's env. variables plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-env-variables/).

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I found the solution and its kind of related to configuration. But its seems to be a difference between the preview and delivery API in so far that the preview API ignores the secure API key and the delivery API does not. I'll raise an issue on GitHub now that I know what it is, as it just needs a better error message.

Comment: The issue was being discussed on [Github](https://github.com/Kentico/gatsby-source-kontent/issues/116)